# Reference request: choiceless cardinality quantifiers

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice

There is a substantial literature on the logic of cardinality quantifiers. (E.g., the quantifier $Q_\alpha$ where $M \vDash Q_\alpha x \, \varphi (x)$ iff $\vert \{a \in M : M \vDash \varphi[a] \} \vert = \aleph_\alpha$.) See, for instance, discussion in Barwise and Feferman, *Model-Theoretic Logics* (Berlin: Springer, 1985).

All the discussions I am aware of, however, presuppose choice in the background framework. In the absence of choice, we can also have quantifiers such as

$$Q^\aleph x \, \varphi (x) \textrm{ iff } \vert \{a \in M : M \vDash \varphi[a] \} \vert \textrm{ is well-orderable};$$

$$Q^\mathfrak{Ded} x \, \varphi (x) \textrm{ iff } \vert \{a \in M : M \vDash \varphi[a] \} \vert \textrm{ is infinite but Dedekind-finite}.$$

(Of course, these become trivial in the presence of choice. For discussion of Dedekind cardinals, see, e.g, Thomas Jech, *The Axiom of Choice* (Amsterdam: North-Holland, 1973).)

Is there any discussion of the behaviour of languages with these quantifiers, given a choiceless background framework, in the literature?

Comment: Not so much, I don't think. But that's a good question!

Comment: I recommend asking Jouko Väänänen about this; if anyone knows the answer, he does.